# Drupal on production with redmine

Tags: drupal, nginx, production-environment

In a production server I have several instances of `redmine` and I wanted to make available on this server a `drupal` instance, too.

I'm following [this tutorial of nginx](https://www.drupal.org/node/1030854) and the install tutorial of `drupal`. I don't want to get those instances offline or worst make them permanently unavailable.

This will happen? Do you have other warnings or tips to this task?